# Most efficient way to track unread messages per user

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a jQuery Mobile Web App where a company will have the ability to message certain groups of users (based on their profile preferences).

I am debating on what is the most efficient way to mark when each user has read the latest messages. I have considered using a session to try and keep track of the last time they opened the messages page, and comparing that to the post times of the messages. I have also considered a table with the message_id and the user_id, marking each one as read when they open the page.

I think both would work, but I am trying to balance the pros and cons. Keeping in a database would allow me to keep a history (especially if i added a timestamp column to know when they read the message), but if it is going to hurt the app performance due to the table size, then it may not be worth it. The app will potentially have 10's of thousands of users.

One thing I should probably mention is that the users may use the app on multiple devices and the app will have very long session times, potentially allowing the user to stay logged in for months. I like the idea that if they read it on one device then it would mark it read on all devices, which may make sessions difficult to work with, right?

Comment: for each message, add a `read` column. Shouldn't be much (if any) of a performance hit. MySQL is a highly powerful piece of database software, and provided you have decent servers and optimization, you'll be able to do millions of records no problem

Comment: I can't just add a read column to the messages table because one message may go from anywhere from one to 1000 users. I was planning on just having one row in the messages table. Would it hurt efficiency to have 1 row in the messages table and a separate table with message_id, uid   to mark them as read?

Comment: Any performance change with that extra table would be negligible (think a couple of milliseconds).

Comment: Also, on a separate note you should not be keeping sessions for months. It is highly insecure as it opens up a much larger window for session hijacking. Rather you should be generating a new session each time the app is accessed, and using a different "remember me" cookie or something each time to authenticate them.

Comment: I believe that's actually what is happening (I didn't write that code personally), but I will double check into it. Thanks

Comment: which would be better/more efficient, a one-to-many table, or having a column in the users table (say, last_read_messages) that's a timestamp and compare it to that users messages and their times. Using that I could get a count of unread messages (for a "bubble" with the number of unread) and not need another table. What are the drawbacks there?

Comment: I've created an answer for my suggestions. Please look at how I've outlined it

Comment: don't suppose you have a notification strategy setup for this. e.g. sending out an email/push if a user hasn't read a message within x minutes? trying to figure out an efficient way of doing this in a similar setup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I'm gonna put everything I said in the comments into one solid answer.

**Short Answer: You should be using the database to store 'read' notifications**

**Logic behind it:**

1. It should be a negligable performance hit with decent servers and optimized code (couple of ms max) even with hundreds of thousands of users
2. It is highly maintainable
3. You can track it and sync it across devices

**Specifically why you shouldn't use sessions**

1. Sessions were designed to store temporary user data (think ram), they're not supposed to log stuff.
2. You should not be keeping sessions for months. It is highly insecure as it opens up a much larger window for session hijacking. Rather you should be generating a new session each time the app is accessed, and using a different "remember me" cookie or something each time to authenticate them.
3. Even if you do make your session persist for months, after those months won't the user all of a sudden get a bajillion "unread" notifications?

**How to store it in the database** 
*This is called a `many-to-many` relationship (from the message perspective) OR a `one-to-many` relationship (from the user perspective)* 
**Table 1: messages**

```
ID, message, timestamp
```

**Table 2: messages_users**

```
ID, user_id, message_id, read
```

**Table 3: users**

```
(Do user business as usual)
```

Comment: so with this method, when I would add a message, i'd add one row to messages, and then one row to messages_users for each user getting the message, and then mark each row as read as they open them to read them, correct?

Comment: @TroubleZero Oxford begs to differ :P http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bajillion

Comment: @livewire1407 or you can just insert the message in table 1 and then create the table 2 record only when user sees the message.

Comment: @KevinPei can you please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220565/how-to-do-when-msg-is-readed-then-color-is-change-or-msg-is-nor-read-its-color

Answer (score -3):

I can do one thing, if no problem with one user or 100 of user, you create one column named `readUnread` with more than 63,999 Characters in which you use put every user your message with 0 and 1 assign like `{jeff:0,kevin:1,Sal:0}` when read update from 0 to 1 and when you open this on the screen, split it with current user and ";", this will help you (this is the logic which inhance your performance).

Comment: There are way more efficient ways to solve this. Storing all in one column actually will have a huge performance drain as for every lookup, some parsing and/or plaintext searching is needed. For every record. It would be a way better idea to add for example a pivot table to store just the ids of users who read the message. This allows to profit from mechanisms like indexing, reliable query caching, and so on. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675865/1248282 for better idea.